# Is there a known method for finding extremely huge squarefree numbers?

Tags: number-theory

People often compete to beat the record for [largest known prime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Largest_known_prime_number) (it is currently $2^{57,885,161}-1$). There are also [big money prizes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_Frontier_Foundation#Awards) for finding explicit prime numbers exceeding specific magnitudes.

But what would happen if you searched for huge *squarefree* integers instead? Is a simple formula known which gives huge squarefree integers? As an example, if it was proved (unexpectedly) that all Fermat numbers $F_m = 2^{2^m}+1$ were squarefree, it would be trivial to find billion-digit squarefree numbers.

Since the asymptotic (natural) density of the squarefree numbers is $\frac{6}{\pi^2}\approx 61\%$ (while for the primes the density is zero), maybe it is much easier to find a simple formula for squarefree numbers?

(It is trivial to come up with a formula yielding huge **non**-squarefree numbers of course, and they constitute only $39\%$.)

I know one can use the sieve of Eratosthenes to generate a list of distinct primes and then take the product of the entire list (a "primorial" number), but can a simpler expression in one integer variable be found to yield only squarefree numbers?

Comment: Well huge squarefree search certainly won't be interesting, as it would just turn into the contest who has the biggest list of prime numbers, which is ridiculous.

Comment: (or a list of comprime squarefree numbers in general)

Comment: @user2345215 There could exist an efficient way of verifying that some huge number, like $2^{2^{65536}}+1$, was squarefree, without actually knowing its factorization (so without having that long list of prime numbers), could there not? If no, why not?

Comment: Maybe. But then it would be easy to prove e.g. $3$ is not a factor ($2^{2^{65536}}+1=4^{2^{65535}}+1\equiv1+1=2$), so we have a bigger squarefree number $3\cdot(2^{2^{65536}}+1)$. Do you see my point?

Comment: @user2345215 Yes, so maybe the record thing does not make much sense, but it is still interesting if some "simple" formula will generate squarefree integers only.

Comment: My understanding is that testing whether a number is squarefree is no easier than testing whether it is prime.

Comment: There is some discussion at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/16098/complexity-of-testing-integer-square-freeness

Comment: @GerryMyerson Very related thread there, thank you. It appears that no fast algorithms are known for testing arbitrary numbers. In principle that does not rule out that some simple formula could generate a (small but infinite) subset of the squarefree numbers, of course, but it seems unlikely.

Comment: The big money prizes for large primes are more ridicolous than a contest who has the biggest list of prime numbers would be.

Comment: @Peter By the way, a new world-record prime number has just been identified; it will be announced this Tuesday at 14:00 UTC.