# Is $2^{2^n}-1$ squarefree?

Tags: number-theory

> Prove that for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ the expression $2^{2^n}-1$ is not divisible by $p^2$ for any prime $p$.

**Note: This question is conjectured by me and may not be true.**

I tried this for some examples up to $n = 10$ and it seems to be true. I was wondering if there were any counterexamples to this problem or if there is a way to prove it.

Comment: Since different Fermat numbers are coprime, the conjecture is equivalent to all Fermat numbers being squarefree. That seems to be [still an open problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/761079/is-there-a-known-method-for-finding-extremely-huge-squarefree-numbers).

Comment: This is equivalent to asking if the multiplicative order of $2$ mod $p^2$ is never a power of $2$. (I checked for the first million primes, and it is never true)

Comment: It is known that, if there are infinitely many square free Mersenne numbers ($2^k-1$) then there are infinitely many non-Wieferich primes, see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wieferich_prime).  However, the latter is very much an open problem.

Comment: @Puzzled417 $$\prod_{k = 0}^n F_k = \prod_{k = 0}^{n} \bigl(2^{2^k}+1\bigr) = 2^{2^{n+1}} - 1.$$ So if your conjecture is true, all Fermat numbers, being divisors of numbers of the form $2^{2^n}-1$, must be squarefree. Conversely the coprimality of different Fermat numbers says that if there is an $n$ such that $2^{2^n}-1$ is not squarefree, then there is a $k < n$ such that $F_k$ is not squarefree.

Comment: No, there's a pesky $\forall$. Proving $\bigl(\forall n\in \mathbb{N}\bigr)\bigl(2^{2^n}-1\text{ is squarefree}\bigr)$ is equivalent to proving $\bigl(\forall n\in \mathbb{N}\bigr)\bigl(2^{2^n}+1\text{ is squarefree}\bigr)$. And proving $2^{2^n}-1$ is squarefree is equivalent to proving that $2^{2^k}+1$ is squarefree for all $k < n$.

Comment: @DanielFischer So that doesn't seem to make the problem much easier by saying they are equivalent.

Comment: @DanielFischer has explained that it is an open problem, often known as "are all Fermat numbers squarefree?". For other "bases" one can find examples, for instance I find that $$(392+1)(392^2+1)(392^4+1)(392^8+1)(392^{16}+1)=392^{32}-1$$ is not squarefree because the prime $769$ is repeated in the factorization of $392^{16}+1$.